# Combine two json source in AngularJS repeat for 'Products' and 'SelectedProducts'

Tags: angularjs

I've got a table that lists all available products based on a json array. I've also got a json array that contains the products the user has previously selected. When I come back to the list of products I want to update the displayed list to show how many you've already choosen of each product.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='product in products'>
    <td>{{product.productId}}</td>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.count}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

(...)

$scope.products = '[{"productId": 1, "name":"Product A", "count": 0},
                    {"productId": 2, "name":"Product B", "count": 0},
                    {"productId": 3, "name":"Product C", "count": 0}]';

$scope.selectedProducts = '[{"productId": 2, "name":"Product B", "count": 5}]';
```

How can I update the products so that I get the correct count on the second product?

Answer (score 0):

In a very robust way you could use filters

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='product in products' ng-init="{{product.count = (selectedProducts | filter:product.name:true)[0].count || 0}}">
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.count}}</td>
  </tr>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tPe0laCPdrXntu7LXa5a?p=preview

otherwise you will have to iterate in your controller over each element to look for a match or you can create a filter to do it in partial or service to put the logic out of controller. I'm afraid there is no magic solution (at least nothing that I can think off from top of my head)

If you are using `$http` for both products and selected products you can utilise promises received from those calls and call the iteration once or destroy watch at a point when you are confident it shouldn't be fired anymore

promises: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

#### promises

```
products = $http.get(//products)
selected = $http.get(//selected)

$q.all([products, selected]).then(function(){
  //do the iteration here
})
```

#### watch

```
watchDestroyer = $scope.$watch('selectedProducts', function (){
  //destroy watch if you are confident there will be no updates
  watchDestroyer()
}, true)
```

Comment: Thank you - could you also show how it can be done with iterating in the Controller? I couldn't get your approach to work with my actual code. Not sure if it's because the json is loaded using $http, or if it's something else.

Comment: I've updated my plunker with iteration in controller with use of watch